# Do people get according to their deeds?

Tags: reality, belief

Do the good and bad deeds of a person pay off? I had seen many of such examples and even heard of many, but I'm quite unsure of whether this is just a belief or are there any ideal principles behind it. If a person does something bad to someone, does he really get back on to himself or it might be just a coincidence?
           I would like to clear that I'm not a philosophy student, though I'm quite interested in and wanna study also. So please do not use such words which may pose more difficulty.

Comment: Some religious systems postulate a metaphysical law of retribution for "bad" deeds, such as going to hell in Christianity or [karma](http://www.theosociety.org/pasadena/gdpmanu/karma/karm-gp.htm) in Oriental philosophies. These involve the "next life", however, to compensate for the obviously limited effectiveness of legal systems and moral conscience in this one. Beyond that there is nothing beyond "vice is its own punishment and virtue is its own reward", I am afraid.

Comment: By your last statement, do you mean that the person who does bad, always feel guilty or demoralised even though he might not admit it in front of others.

Comment: Not necessarily, although people do interpret it that way. But philosophers can mean it more objectively: vice diminishes person's value and virtue inhances is, whether they feel anything or not, admit it or not, care or not. Just as color blind people, who never learn that they are color blind, would still miss something.

Comment: Nice example of colourblinds. Can this might be a reason that many of such persons don't lead a happy life although they pretend to be happy in front of the world?

Comment: They do not have to pretend, to *them* what they have *is* happiness. It is to a happier (more ethical?) person that the deficiency becomes apparent. One needs to experience the colors to appreciate what they are missing. Of course, this is controversial. One could say instead that moral and non-moral perspectives are both subjective, and neither is any more "true" than the ther, and that the correlation with "happiness" is questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the perennial philosophy the laws of causation (in an ethical context) apply to intentions and motivations, not to deeds. If we help an old lady across the road and she gets run over half way across we are not marked down for this since it has nothing to do with our intentions. A teaching story has it that Buddha committed a murder in a previous life in order to save others from being murdered. The deed seems reprehensible, but the motive is what counts.

The punishment and rewards would be self-administered and this would be why we cannot escape our fate, that we will be our own judge and jury. We were there and know exactly our state of mind and intentions at the time. Socrates indicates this view when he says,'The price of a lack of virtue is a disordered soul'. A disordered soul would be its own punishment, just as virtue would be its own reward.

Ignorance of the effects of actions would be a valid excuse, but a failure to  make any attempt to dispel our ignorance would have no excuse. Feigning ignorance would be impossible and pointless because no outside agency would be judging us. When a rock falls off a cliff it follows the laws of the universe all the way to the bottom, and the laws of karma would be just the same for falling humans.

What this would mean is that are no blanket rules. As the OP says, murder, criminal acts etc. are not always wrong since context is everything. Purity of heart would overcome all ethical errors and this would be connected to the teaching that those who are enlightened, thus free from any egoic tendency to think or act to the detriment of others, transcend the legacy of their karmic history.

This seems to be in line with the idea mentioned in another reply that it is the state of our consciousness that matters, and that determines the strength of the connection between our deeds and their consequences.

Comment: Ignorance of the effects of actions would be a valid excuse, but a failure to make any attempt to dispel our ignorance would have no excuse.  I didn't understand this statement well. Can you please explain this.

Comment: @Vidhi Gupta Sure. Ignorance of the effects of our actions may be a fair excuse when they are not as we expected and in any case we never know the full effect of our actions. We may mean well but have made a mistake as to how to act. But meaning well is a poor excuse when we have made no effort to understand our situation.  As well as the details the 'situation' would include who we are and what sort of world we live in. Thus in mysticism great emphasis placed on dispelling ignorance prior getting busy trying to help people, for our efforts are likely to be ineffective or backfire. .

Answer (score 1):

According to Indian Vedic scriptures The answer to above question depends on what kind of person he/she is. There are three main kinds of people, namely,
***1) Sattvik
2) Rajas
3)Tamas***

Then there are thousands of types derived of permutations of these basic types. IF the person is more on ***Sattvik*** side, He becomes more aware of his consciousness and so the results of his deeds come faster and clearer, while if he lies near the ***Tamasik*** side , He becomes more and more unaware of his consciousness and consequently his deeds, Therefore the results of his deeds come slower and unclear . An animal or a plant are towards ***Tamasik*** side , as the level of there consciousness is very low compared to most of the humans ,  while the gods and goddesses depicted in scriptures have a higher level of consciousness than humans as they are near  the ***Sattvik*** side of this scale of consciousness.
**So, it depends on the consciousness of person.**

Comment: And what about rajas as you didn't describe it?

Comment: As well, if a person lies near tamasik side, he becomes more unaware of his consciousness and the results of his deeds are thus slower as you said. What does that mean? It implies to me like anyone who does wrong should become unaware of what he did or forget his bad deed, he will have unclear results meaning he will never be able to regret on his doings and consequently will continue his doings?? Please explain.

Comment: Rajas is where most of the humans lie, It is a state where The person is Attached to all worldly things, रजो रागात्मको  as described in Bhagvad gita, Rajas is filled with Attachments, So  it is somewhere in between those two states. Results are slower and unclearer than the sattvik state but faster and clearer than the Tamasik state.

Comment: If everybody can derive easily that whatever sorrow, grief they are experiencing is the result of their previous deeds, nobody would ever do such deeds and the world would come to an end, because everybody will get moksha. So it is Maya which creates a veil before the eyes of a person so that he cannot derive the truth easily. The mechanism of doing so is as described in my post

Comment: The mechanism is Automatically such that , Good is attracted to more good and Bad to bad.

Comment: "If everybody can derive easily that whatever sorrow, grief they are experiencing is the result of their previous deeds", by this statement should I contemplate the answer to my question that a person is surely paid off for his deeds. As because whatever grief or happiness is he experiencing is the actual outcome of his previous deeds, though its true that all might not be able to derive the truth easily??

Comment: ya, you can conclude that, But the time taken in ripening of Karma can be different in different persons.

Comment: Sorry to go off-question but can we then guarantee that person will not die before ripening of his karma? Though that might sound weird, but it's actually controversial. Its philosophy, so I can argue. The conclusion which I brought about in whole of our discussions will be fake??

Comment: It won't be fake because if we take The Karma concept as the basis of this discussion, In the context of your latest argument, There will be rebirth and the Karma will continue to play it's role in new life too.

Comment: upvote if you liked the answer

Comment: I am not that reputed for my votes to be displayed. Haha! But they have been recorded. Had an interesting argument with you. Thanks